# Add image under menu on mouseover

Tags: html, css, menu

Here's my code

http://jsfiddle.net/6748w/

I would like that the imgs/fleche_bleue.png in my CSS to appear under the hovered menu. I can't figured it out.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/6748w/20/

See the small arrow under the mouse over, that's what I want without the glitch it make !!

Comment: This isn't going to work, because `imgs/fleche_bleue.png` isn't in JSFiddle, how is JSFiddle supposed to have access to that directory?

Comment: Added an image so you can see the arrow....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/NKRZG/

Comment: Nice NICE!!! That's what I wanted. Now need to make it cross-browser compatible and stick it under the menu without the margin.

Answer (score 1):

When you hovered over the link, the position moved. Since it moved out of range of the mouse, it moved back to it's original position. This kept repeating until the mouse was moved completely away. All I did was remove the top:30px.

(Also I added a background color since the image did not load just to show that it works.)

http://jsfiddle.net/6748w/18/

Comment: I don't want the explantion why it make that flickering. I want a solution to make it work with the arrow that stays there.